# Как лучше обрабатывать данные из .txt файла в python?

Tags: python, файлы

Ситуация следующая: есть достаточно большой текстовый файл (порядка миллиона длинных строк), нужно его распарсить.
*Если важна конкретика:* достать координаты точек, т.е. в результате получается двумерный массив, каждый элемент которого это x,y,z.

С данными из этого файла в дальнейшем будут проводить некоторые сложные манипуляции, т.е. будут проверяться некоторые условия на координаты, а также для каждой точки будет цикл по другому огромному массиву, где, опять же, будут происходить математические операции.

К сути дела. Как лучше поступить с точки зрения скорости и памяти (да и в целом, что является в данном случае хорошей практикой):

1. Открыть файл, прочитать одну точку из него, и для нее сразу же, не закрывая файл и не продолжая считывание, производить действия описанные выше (т.е. пробег по еще одному массиву, математические операции). И так для каждой точки (т.е. файл висит открытым на протяжении работы всего алгоритма).
2. Достать из файла двумерный массив точек. Закрыть файл. И уже потом делать с каждой точкой из этого массива вышеуказанные действия.

Очень прошу подробного ответа, важно быстродействие кода.

Я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, т.к. мне кажется, что лучше сначала достать все из файла, закрыть его и делать уже что хочешь...

Если ни один из двух вариантов не кажется хорошим, предложите свой.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А в каждой строке помимо координат есть другой текст? Если да, то этот текст имеет в себе только буквы и знаки или цифры в ненужном тексте тоже есть? Координаты как то выделены в тексте (скобками или кавычками)?

Comment: Выглядит строка так:  -1 /(n пробелов)/число[/(' ' или '-')/цифра/'.'/цифра/цифра/цифра/цифра/цифра/'E'/('+ ' или '-')/цифра/цифра]. Квадратная скобка повторяется еще дважды (для Y,Z соответственно). По сути некоторое регулярное выражение получается. Как его прочитать я разобрался. Вопрос сугубо в том, будет ли как-то негативно влиять на производительность тот факт, что мы все делаем с открытым файлом

Comment: Наверное могу ввести в заблуждение символами /. Где стоит /, там просто конкатенация

Comment: Если честно я запутался) можете привести пример строки и того, какие x y z для этой строки?)

Comment: Пример: -1      1257-7.86818E-02-4.28874E+02 4.39651E-01
Координаты: X: -0.0786818  Y:-428.874  Z: 0.439651
Число 1257 в начале, это порядковый номер точки. -1 в начале вообще просто так

Comment: Ох боюсь тут сложно будет, с учетом того, что числа не разделены пробелами и запятыми...
Могу лишь только подсказать, что 'float(-7.86818E-02)' = -0.0786818 будет выводить число с плавающей точкой, соответствующее x y z, а вот как выделить эту часть строки-куда более сложная задача...

Comment: Либо Вы меня не понимаете, либо я Вас :) Я смог получить их в виде чисел, это не сложно, в этом у меня проблемы нет. Вопрос у меня такой: будет ли ухудшаться скорость работы программы, если я буду производить действия с открытым файлом, или время будет таким же, как если бы я просто считал это с файла и закрыл его.

Comment: Аааа, пардон, я не так понял) Если вы будете работать с этими данными в виде таблицы(в каждой строке x y z), то я рекомендовал бы не использовать все время текстовый файл, лучше из текстового сделать .csv, а лучше .piclke или .feather, а уже потом работать с ним, загружая содержимое в датафрейм(таблицу), для этого подойдет Pandas, скорость работы должна быть точно выше, чем при работе с текстовым файлом огромного размера, да и с данными будет удобнее работать в pandas

Comment: Единственное-конвертация из текстового файла в датафрейм, а затем в .csv(или другие) займет немало времени, тк потребуется создать 3 массива для x y z, а затем на их основе создать датафрейм, это значит что придется пройтись циклом по всем строкам и добавлять значения в 3 массива, каждый из них будет длинной как количество строк в текстовом файле. Зато потом будет удобнее работать. Только надо знать, данные из txt окончательные или они будут туда добовляться постоянно?

Comment: Данные добавляться не будут, txt окончательный

Comment: тогда лучше всего извлечь данные в датафрейм pandas, а затем сохранить в формате .pickle например, а далее использовать его, этот формат лучше csv, тк меньше весит, быстрее загружается и сохраняется, специально для большого обьема данных, также вы сказали, что с данными надо будет тоже произвести манипуляции, это тоже удобнее делать в pandas. Вот видео по csv, pickle, feather, там показано, чем отличаются эти типы фалов при больших обьемах данных https://youtu.be/u4rsA5ZiTls

Comment: Благодарю. Я тоже к таким методам склоняюсь. Однако, все-таки, интересно, действительно ли при открытом файле все будет работать медленнее и как это можно объяснить с точки зрения работы языка. Видимо, буду проводить эксперименты, чтобы выяснить

Comment: Поидее при открытии файл переносится в оперативную память, а так как он большой и тем более в нем много лишних данных, то это нерациональное использование озу, если оперативки много-то особо разницы не будет поидее, но если вы будете много раз запускать код, то каждый раз на открытие и загрузку txt будет уходить много времени, поэтому вариант с pandas лучше, тк он использует C под копотом и быстрее питона, да и в датафрейме уже не будет лишних данных, если будете проводить замеры-напишите потом пожалуйста результаты)

Comment: Спасибо. По поводу памяти., вычисления производятся на сервере, доступно 128GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из предложенных вами вариантов, правильнее всего будет как раз таки держать файл открытым и читать данные из него построчно. В таком случае будет создан файловый объект, представляющий собой открытый файл, но сам файл не будет загружен в оперативную память, что позволяет вам работать в ограниченном по памяти пространстве. Однако как вы подметили ранее, сам файл на всём протяжении работы программы будет открыт, это не должно создавать особых проблем, максимум возникнут проблемы с доступом к этому же файлу у других программ, пока файл не будет закрыт.

```
def read_file(path: str):  # Пример построчного чтения файла на примере гениратора
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            yield line
```

Во втором варианте все данные из файла будут выгружены в оперативную память, что может создать куда более серьёзные проблемы, в случае если количество оперативной памяти будет ограничено, вплоть до вылета всей системы. Зато быстродействие возрастёт т.к. все данные уже доступны и к ним можно быстро получить доступ, да и если во время работы нужно будет обращаться к другим строкам из этого же файла, то этот метод будет предпочтительнее первого.

Выбор третьего из двух вам предложили в комментариях - использовать другие типы файлов вроде `csv`, `pickle` и им подобных. На счёт производительности ничего конкретно сказать не могу, ибо не замерял, могу только предположить: в `csv` данные структурированы, и для чтения их средствами `python` может занять немного больше времени чем чтение текстового файла (без учёта того, что вы также выполняете парсинг данных). Но если учитывать, что вы можете использовать специализированные библиотеки, таких как `pandas`, для чтения данных из файлов `CSV` может быть более эффективным и удобным, чем чтение данных из текстового файла. Как итог если предположить, что этот метод лучше первых двух по производительности, он всё равно имеет один важный недочёт, данные сначала надо конвертировать из `txt` в `csv` (или другой формат), что требует лишних действий и времени.

На крайняк можно после чтения каждой строки закрывать файл, при этом запоминая текущую позицию, а после снова открывать файл и перепрыгивать на нужную позицию методом `.seek()`. Но я этого не советую, ибо будет тратиться время ещё и на на открытие/закрытие файла.

И всё же всё индивидуально. 1М строк это не так и много в нашем времени, поэтому можно использовать любой из методов, при учёте что у вас всё-таки достаточно ОЗУ :)

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ! По поводу памяти, вычисления производятся на сервере, память -128GB. Важно именно быстродействие. Поэтому, как и думал, буду использовать 2) вариант.